# Convert XML self closing tags to open and closing tag

Tags: c#, .net, regex, xml

I have an string that is a full XML documento where i should replace self closing tags to opening and closing tag.

For example: `<name />`

Should be converted to: `<name></name>`

I tried without regex with:

```
myXML.Replace("<name />","<name></name>");
```

Works but only for this tag, that is the resaon why i would like to do it with regex, to support all possible XML tags of the XML Document without doing a replace of a particular XML node.

I accept any suggestion to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally: why? They are perfectly valid. If you insist: `<(.*?)\s*/>` and replace this with `<$1></$1>`, see a demo here: https://regex101.com/r/P4qmhR/1

Comment: What is the tags contain attributes? @Jan, that regex is unsafe since `.` matches any char.

Comment: See a demo on ideone.com additionally: https://ideone.com/zP6VGv

Comment: Start with Regex: (?<Node><([a-z,A-Z])+(\w|\s)*/>)    and then evolve it to better suit all the cases in your xml.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Of course, [**`<([^<>/]+)/>`**](https://regex101.com/r/P4qmhR/2/) works as well.

Comment: @Jan, XML can contain an unserialized `>` inside the attribute values.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That's why I wouldn't use regular expressions in the first place, here.

Comment: [Mandatory link ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Jan yes i know are valid, but later the client rejects it because i suppose they have a custom XML validator made by them and they don't accept self-closing tags.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew XML nodes in this case don't have attributes and in case it have won't be in self-closing tags.

Comment: @Miguel You should provide any specific details in the question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman that is not acceptable. Obviosly i can generate always nodes with a fixed string which would never appear in nodes generated by the user and later make a .Replace of that string, but i would prefer avoid that ugly approach at this moment (that would be my last option).

Comment: @Jan your option worked. I think it fails if node has attributes but as said, in this case don't have so no problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an answer as well: You may use

```
<(.*?)\s*/>
```

and replace this with `<$1></$1>`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](http://regex101.com/r/P4qmhR/1).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will put potential attributes on the closing tag aswell as the opening tag.

I had to create closing tags for a collection of SVGs to support IE11. Use the following solution, if you need to have attributes only on the opening tag.

Find: `<([a-z]+)+(.*?)\s*/>`
Replace: `<$1$2></$1>`

This solution creates two different regex groups. `$1` contains the XML tag. `$2` contains the attributes.

Comment: If you are looking for many elements to replace that has elements already transformed,
use `/<([a-z]+)+([^><]*?)\s*\/>/g`, it works for me.